# The difference between 选择 and 选取?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

In Chinese so many words look like the same and I could not understand which one to use. Now, I wonder in what kind of situations I should use 选择 or 选取 over the other to express "choose" or "select".

In most cases I saw 选择 used, but when you connect to Wi-Fi on iPhone, it shows "选取网络".

So what is the difference and how can I use it according to my needs properly?

Comment: bkrs:  **选取**  ，synonyms: 挑选, 拣选, 精选, 挑拣, 选择, 抉择, 取舍, 挑, 选, 拣, 择, 摘, 卜, 挑三拣四, 选项, 挑挑拣拣, 选萃, 捎   **选择**  ，synonyms ：卜, 取舍, 抉择, 拣, 拣选, 择, 挑, 挑三拣四, 挑拣, 挑挑拣拣, 挑选, 捎, 摘, 精选, 选, 选取, 选萃, 选项  online dictionaries supply many examples allowing users to make the correct choice
in any given context

Comment: selectively 选择性地: e.g.西方选择性地看待恐怖主义

Comment: 选取 pick up / choose;   选择 making a decision.  So 选择 can be used for abstract things, like policy.

Comment: 取: get, puck. so 选取 means **select and get** it, the first character 选 means 选择 here.

Comment: 取: get, pick. 选取 means **选择**并**取得**, select and get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 选择 means 'to select'

E.g: 选择人才 - select talents (after selected the talented people, the selector can decided what to do with them.)

> 选取 means 'to select and take in (accept or employ)

E.g: 选取進士- select and taking in palace graduates
(It is an official government selection of officer candidates, all selected will be accepted as 進士)

If you wrote 选择進士, that would mean you are selecting someone among a group of 進士. (Again, after selected, the government can decide what to do with them)

> *In most cases I saw 选择 used, but when you connect to Wi-Fi on iPhone, it shows "选取网络"*.

"选择网络" = select network (after selected, you can decide to connect, disconnect or delete from list)

"选取网络" = select and connect to this network

Also, 选择 can be a noun or verb; 选取 is a verb

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry too much on this one. The only difference, if you really argue there should be any, is that 选取 sounds more formal and elegant, and you probably will see it more being used in publications like academic research papers.

Answer (score 1):

There could some overlaps in usage of these twos, but there is a general opinion for the distinction between them.

选择 emphasizes that you should think deep/hard to make your choice and somehow must be more careful to your answer/choice in order not to make a wrong decision or bad choice. For example, there are 4 answers for a question you can select from. You have to think hard to get a correct one. That question is called 选择题， not 选取题. Once you decide, you would say 我选择A,B,C or D in this case.

选取 is somehow the formal way to say 'you could generally get one'. In oral Chinese, we just say 选. 选取网络 will be said like 选一个网络. So, 选取 could be based on your knowledge, feelings, opinions, rule of thumb and etc. 选取 also implies that you should go get it after the selection. 选取网络，for example, you should go click it after the selection.